# Как вывести список списков в Python в нужном виде?

Tags: python

Дан начальный список:
`[1,2,3,4,5]`
Нужно вывести список списков вида:
`[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,1], [3,4,5,1,2], [4,5,1,2,3], [5,1,2,3,4]]`
Что мне нужно исправить в коде,чтобы получить правильный результат?[image]

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
x=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.append(a.pop(0))
    x.append(a)
    print(x)
```

Comment: а где же код, в котором «нужно исправить»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
x=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    x.append(a.copy())
    a.append(a.pop(0))
    print(x)
```

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Использование [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) позволяет писать лаконичный код для таких задач:

```
from queue import deque

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

d = deque(l)
result = []
for _ in range(len(d)):
    result.append(list(d))
    d.append(d.popleft())
print(result)
```

Comment: и самое главное оптимальный)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, про оптимальность тут еще говорить рано, пока задача сформулирована как просто вывод данных.

Comment: Все равно приятно получить самый эффективный алгоритмический способ, причем с легким синтаксисом. Ваш вариант по моим оценкам в 15-20 раз быстрее всех перечисленных ответов)

Comment: Насчет синтаксиса согласен (ради этого и опубликовал ответ), а насчет эффективности алгоритма - нет, так как нет конкретной задачи. При существенном увеличении размера входного списка в первую очередь упремся в дорогой вывод. Да и возникает вопрос, а зачем вообще выводить эти данные.

Comment: вот если исправить код так чтобы получился список списков как в вопросе, то это был бы самый оптимальный вариант решения)

Comment: @MaxU, ок. Я просто как-то подумал, что если нужен только вывод, то какая разница, список там или просто в строку.

Answer (score 0):

В лоб:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = []

for j in range(len(x)):
    y = []

    for i in range(len(x)):
        y.append(x[(i + j) % len(x)])

    z.append(y)

print(z)
```

чуть покороче вариант:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = []

for j in range(len(x)):
    z.append(list(map(lambda i : x[(i + j) % len(x)], range(len(x)))))

print(z)
```

и совсем коротко:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = list(map(lambda j: list(map(lambda i : x[(i + j) % len(x)], range(len(x)))), range(len(x))))

print(z)
```

и ещё чуть покороче:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = list(map(lambda j, s=len(x): list(map(lambda i: x[(i + j) % s], range(s))), range(len(x))))

print(z)
```

и ещё чуть покороче :)

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = [*map(lambda j, s=len(x): [*map(lambda i: x[(i + j) % s], range(s))], range(len(x)))]

print(z)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за несколько вариантов!

Comment: @Herzanet, по идее это все один и тот же вариант, но свёрнутый постепенно в одну строку без использования каких-то дополнительных функций

Answer (score 0):

Можно при помощи генератора:

```
a = list(range(1, 6))
[a[i:] + a[:i] for i in range(len(a))]

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
 [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Немного быстрее, чем вариант выше

```
%%timeit
[a[i:] + a[:i] for i in range(len(a))]
1.12 µs ± 6.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

x = list(range(1, 6))
list(map(lambda j: list(map(lambda i : x[(i + j) % len(x)], range(len(x)))), range(len(x))))
5.86 µs ± 27.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Исходные данные
a = list(range(1,6))

# Результат
x = [sorted(a, key=lambda item: item % e) for e in a]
```

---

### Объяснение:

1. `lambda item: item % e` - функция, возвращающая остаток от деления на `e`;
2. `sorted(a, key=lambda item: item % e)` - сортированный список `a`. Сортируем по остатку от деления на `e`;
3. `[sorted(a, key=lambda item: item % e) for e in a]` - список отсортированных списков `a` по остатку от деления на `e` для каждого `e` из `a`.

Comment: а будет ли это решение работать для списка, который изначально не отсортирован?

Comment: @MaxU Не будет. Что дано, на то и ответ.